# Linking the files saved in a Desktop folder to the list of items already existed through PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, hyperlink

The following code fetches around 100 records of judgment from mysql table in the form of a list which contains case nos., title, etc. I have a separate folder on desktop which contains pdf files of these judgments. This folder or files in it has no link with mysql table. Is there any way that when user click on any of the case no., judgment of such case no. would open in the browser or through pdf reader.

I don't know how to link files lying in the folder on desktop to the item in the list dynamically, which means each item of the list on click should open the pdf file corresponding to it.

```
<?php

        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', '');

        $sql="SELECT case when ordertype=1 then 'Judgement' else 
                'Order' end ordertype, casetype, caseno, year, petitioner, 
                respondent, firstcoram, secondcoram, thirdcoram, fourthcoram, 
                fifthcoram, cavon, pronouncementdate, questionoflaw FROM `cav` 
                WHERE writtenby ='1' and ordertype='1' and  
                CAST(`pronouncementdate` AS CHAR(10)) != '0000-00-00' ORDER BY 
                pronouncementdate ASC";
        $query = $conn->query($sql);
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);    
        $i=0;
        $date = date('d-m-Y');  
        echo '<BR><BR><BR><BR>

        <h2 align="center">Judgement delivered by       as on 
                '.$date.'</h2>
        <CENTER><table border=".05" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
        <tr>
            <th>S.No.</th>
            <th>Case No.</th>
            <th width="17%" >Cause Title</th>
            <th>Question of Law</th>
            <th>Coram</th>
            <th>Judgment/ Order</th>
            <th>CAV Date</th>
            <th>Judgment Pronounced On</th>
            </tr> ';

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $i++;
        echo"
        <tr>
            <td>".$i."</td>
            <td>".$row["casetype"]." ".$row["caseno"]."/".$row["year"]." 
                </td>
            <td>".$row["petitioner"]."<br>Vs.<br>".$row["respondent"]." 
                </td>
            <td>".$row["questionoflaw"]."</td>
            <td>".$row["firstcoram"]."<br>".$row["secondcoram"]." 
                <br>".$row["thirdcoram"]."<br>".$row["fourthcoram"]." 
                <br>".$row["fifthcoram"]."</td>
            <td>".$row["ordertype"]."</td>
            <td>".date_format(date_create($row["cavon"]),'d-m-Y')."</td>
            <td>".date_format(date_create($row["pronouncementdate"]),'d-m- 
                Y')."</td>
        </tr>
        ";
        }
        echo"
        </CENTER></table>";
        ?>
```

I wish that Case No. should be made clickable (having hyperlink) and when the user clicks any of the Case No. appears in the list, it should open the corresponding pdf file lying in the folder available on my desktop.

Comment: whose desktop exactly? A web application can't open files on the client machine (i.e. the machine where the browser is running). If the files are located on the server, then you could make PHP output hyperlinks to them, so that when the user clicks on the link it would open the document from the URL on the server. Obviously for that to work your mysql table will need to contain some sort of information which associates it with the correct document - e.g. the filename and/or full path, or an ID or other data from which the correct filename could be constructed according to a fixed pattern.

Comment: P.S. as an aside, please never get your web app to login to the database as root. Root has full admin rights,
so if you app has any security vulnerability
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.
Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Comment: P.P.S. Are you targeting a very old browser with this HTML? You appear be using lots of things which are deprecated and are therefore at risk of being removed in future browser versions (e.g. `<center>` and `cellspacing`, using lots of `<br>`s for spacing -  that kind of thing. I suggest you maybe take some time to update your knowledge so you're aware of current HTML5 and CSS technologies, and avoid implementing new code using legacy techniques. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5 has a comprehensive set of guidance.

Comment: Thanks Dyson for your quick response and valuable suggestions, these files are lying in a folder on my desktop in the computer in which the server and mysql database is installed.  Is there no way to link these pdf files to the list, without uploading them?

Comment: If they're already in the same machine where PHP and mysql is installed, then they're already on the server. You just need to move them to a folder where the webserver can access them